# What is the mathematical notation for the mode of a distribution?

Tags: notation

Am writing an economics paper wherein defining a dummy variable as a taking the value one if the value of one variable is greater than the mode of another.

What would be the best way to write this formally?

I thought perhaps 
$$
Y_i=1 \mbox{ if }\, X_i>\mathrm{argmax}\, X_j \; \forall\, i \,in \, j
$$

but this seems like overkill for something as simple as the mode.

All thoughts appreciated on this vital philosophical q!

Comment: Thanks for the LaTex correction - can I assume the rest is okay however?